# How can i target below dropdown list which in div

Tags: watir-webdriver

MY CODE : i would like target the select option in select drop down list with below code

```
b.select_list(:css => 'select').select("POSTPONED")
```

but it is not updating and giving not found error

```
#<option value="" disabled="" selected="">-- Choose Option --</option>


#<option value="IN PROGRESS">In Progress</option>

#<option value="UPCOMING">Upcoming</option>

<option value="FINAL" selected="selected">Final</option>

<option value="POSTPONED">Postponed</option>

<option value="CANCELLED">Cancelled</option>
```

Comment: Can you post the error that you get when you run your code? Can you post the HTML for the select list?

Comment: <div class="component-select-dropdown form-component" data-<select>
  
    #<option value="" disabled="" selected="">-- Choose Option --</option>
  
  
    #<option value="IN PROGRESS">In Progress</option>
  
    #<option value="UPCOMING">Upcoming</option>
  
    <option value="FINAL" selected="selected">Final</option>
  
    <option value="POSTPONED">Postponed</option>
  
    <option value="CANCELLED">Cancelled</option>
  
</select>

Comment: added extra details , please have a look , i think some i am  tricky thing  is missing @Johnson

Comment: Are you asking how to find a select list in a div or how to select from a list? Please try to fully explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@johnson : I have tried to with your code , its not working , its a bit tricky one we need to select based on div

```
b.div(:class => 'form-component').select(:css => 'select').select('In Progress')
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML:

```
<select id="some_list">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="">-- Choose Option --</option>
  <option value="IN PROGRESS">In Progress</option>
  <option value="UPCOMING">Upcoming</option>
  <option value="FINAL" selected="selected">Final</option>
  <option value="POSTPONED">Postponed</option>
  <option value="CANCELLED">Cancelled</option>
</select>
```

You can use the [`select`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Select#select-instance_method) method to pick an option based on the text.  For example:

```
browser.select_list(:id => "some_list").select "Postponed"
```

If you want to select an option based on the value attribute, you can use the [`select_value`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Select#select_value-instance_method) method:

```
browser.select_list(:id => "some_list").select_value("POSTPONED")
```

Comment: Moving my answer here, since this deserves the correct answer:

Expanding on orde's answer, here's what I'd do for your specific code:

`b.select(:xpath, "//select").select_value("POSTPONED")`
This will only work if the select element is the only one on the page. If there are more select elements, you'll need a more specific xpath.